# WSO2 API Manager Https

Tags: java, https, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to configure WSO2 Api Manager on a windows machine. I have used yajsw to install api manager as a windows service. I am accessing /publisher on port 9443 and publishing a GET type API. I am subscribing the API from the store. When I test this from the API console in the store I am getting error.

> 404 - File or directory not found

I am pasting the cURL request for this -

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/html' --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' 'https://path url'
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you getting same errror when invoking the API using above curl command ? any message in wso2carbon.log ?

Comment: I am getting this message when I hit 'Try it out' from the swagger console - 
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-01-18 23:08:10,417]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  This engine will expire all callbacks after : 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}

Comment: curl command works for you ?

Comment: i am trying using Postman. I get the same result from there also ? I am configuring it on machine which is behind a enterprise proxy server ? Can that cause something like this

Comment: Now I am getting this error - Please help - 
ERROR DeferredMessageBuilder Error building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input.

Comment: you need to add the complete request with payload and wirelog to the question. Otherwise it is hard to troubleshoot.  Guide to enable wirelog can be found here http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Comment: Below is the wire log -